# Localizar elemento no HTML e adicionar uma classe com JavaScript puro

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp

Preciso localizar uma classe chamada `uk-slideshow` dentro do HTML, após localizar, preciso verificar dentro da estrutura do `uk-slideshow` possui imagem, caso tenha, adicione uma classe nesta *img*. PS: É mais de uma imagem.
A estrutura do *HTML* é assim:

```
<div>
<ul class="uk-slideshow">
    <li>
        imagem
    </li>
    <li>
        imagem
    </li>
</ul>
```

Com *jQuery* é bem mais prático e faria desta forma:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.uk-slideshow > li img').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("via-img-banner");
});
```

})

Mas preciso fazer isso em *JS* nativo.
Tentei fazer desta forma:

```
<script>var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("uk-slideshow").getElementsByTagName("img");slide.add("via-img-no-lazy");</script>
```

Como poderia fazer isso?
Vou aplicar isso no *WordPress*, sei que o *jQuery* seria a melhor opção, mas devido a utilização de um plugin, vou executar esse código diretamente do head.

Comment: Se vc quer pegar todas as imagens pq não usa o seletor direto no css `.uk-slideshow > li > img`, não entendi a necessidade de adicionar uma classe  mais

Comment: Estou configurando um plugin de Lazy Load, no plugin, vou inserir essa classe para que a imagem seja ignorada.

Comment: Cuidado que esse seletor `.uk-slideshow > li img` está errado, não vai encontrar nada, porque entre a div e as `<li>` existe uma `<ul>`. Ao usar o sinal `>` vc está dizendo que as `<li>` são filhas diretas da div, o que não é verdade. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar o `addEventListenner` no `document` para capturar quando o DOM for totalmente carregado e, após isso, usar o `querySelectorAll` para capturar uma lista de elementos usando o seletor CSS destes, iterar nestes elementos e adicionar a classe manualmente:

```
<script language="javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        var imgList = document.body.querySelectorAll(".uk-slideshow > li img");
        for (let i = 0; i < imgList.length; i++) {
            imgList[i].classList.add(" via-img-banner");                
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Que é isso, qualquer coisa é só perguntar

Comment: O código ficou bom, mas tem um erro. Dá uma olhada no meu comentário lá em cima. ;)

Comment: Não conhecia esta propriedade classList e nem lembrava do IE :P, obrigado.

Comment: @Sam, foi falta de atenção minha. A classe do uk-slideshow fica na ul mesmo. Corrigi no código da pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Uma outra forma seria usando `.classList.add()` com um `for` tradicional, já que o `forEach` não tem suporte no Internet Explorer.

Note que o seletor `".uk-slideshow > ul img"` irá buscar todas as tags `<img>` que encontrar dentro da `<ul>` filha da `div.uk-slideshow`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   
   var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".uk-slideshow > ul img");
   for(var x=0; x<imgs.length; x++) imgs[x].classList.add("via-img-banner");
   
});
```

```html
<div class="uk-slideshow">
   <ul>
       <li>
           <img>
       </li>
       <li>
           <img>
       </li>
       <li>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```